# How to insert an empty row into an dynamic column CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using a CSS grid that dynamically spans cells across the full with and break to a new line if no space left. So far so good (see below):

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
    grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

But now I would like to insert an empty row spaning over the full with beginning from the beginning. Like this:

```
a   a   a   a
a   a   a
X   X   X   X
a   a   a   a
a   a
```

Is this possible with CSS grid and how?

Thx for your support!

Comment: No. You would have to insert an additional element that spans all columns

Comment: what are the conditions? after how many elements? etc

Comment: well it should be flexible. So if a certain condition is true I would like to insert a new line. I cannot say after 4rd or 7th etc. element yet.

Answer (score -2):

Sure you can achieve by using `grid-column: 1 / -1;`

```
.grid-container > div:nth-child(7) { /*  add your required row to fill */
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).